# SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class' on implementing phantomjs in angular 8 application

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner, angular8

I am trying to implement phantom js in angular 8 application by following below steps:

1. `npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev`
2. `npm install intl --save`
3. Add `import 'core-js/client/shim';` and `import intl;` to polyfills.ts.

I am getting following syntax error on running `ng test`:

```
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:22707:0
```

Kindly guide me for this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `target` in `tsconfig.spec.json` to `es5` instead of the default `es6`

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "target": "es5",  <<<========== add this line
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `polyfills.ts` file:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```